# Landsat 5 cloud free image GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-5

I'm building random forest models to track land use in Google Earth Engine. To do so I need to select a single cloud free image to use to generate training pixels and ultimately use to produce my classified image. I've been able to do this for Landsat 8 but I can't figure out the code for Landsat 5 and was hoping someone would know how I can do this.

Does anyone know if there's a bit of code I can include to select a cloud free image for Landsat 5? I've tried the code I included for Landsat 8 but it doesn't work for Landsat 5: `.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20);`

I've included the code I'm using below.

```
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2010-03-01', '2010-10-01');

function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);  

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'True Color (321)');
Map.centerObject(ROI);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccc43c0e303f5394c019a1cfebc5f248

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you did not specify why the cloud filtering doesn't work or why you are unhappy with it. Does it raise some kind of error? Or do you just don't get a cloudfree image by only filtering? For me this works just fine with you code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2010-07-01', '2010-08-01')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 20);
```

Maybe you had `;` behind your `.filterDate()`? This raises the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:5)

By the way: you could also think about creating a Landsat 5 composite image for your desired time period. This way there is a higher chance of getting a cloud free image. This would look something like this:

```
var L5composite = dataset.median().clip(country);
Map.addLayer(L5composite,{bands:['SR_B3','SR_B2','SR_B1'],min:6000, max:13300},'L5 composite');
```

(I know asking for clarification in the answer is not desired but I don't have the reputation to comment yet).